# HashMap borks my values

Tags: java

```
HashMap<String, int[]> H = new HashMap<String, int[]>(); 
H.put("drdetroit", new int[]{1,2});
H.put("drdetroit", new int[]{1,3}); 
System.out.println(H.get("drdetroit").toString());
```

It prints out

```
[I@c3c749
```

I assume this is the hashed value(is it?). How can I make it print my actual values?

Comment: If you want to print the values of an array using `toString()` on that array, you will get something completely different from the values, it does not matter if it is in a HashMap or not. Use `Arrays.toString(array)` instead

Comment: Also your hashmap will only print the first value so don't get confused. :)

Comment: @limelights: How can I make it print both of them=

Comment: You have to change the second key to something unique since HashMaps stores only unique keys. So `H.put('drdetroit', value);` and `H.put('drchicago', value);` will work for you

Comment: @limelights: Is there an object that I can use that allows multiple values per key?

Comment: Nah, but you can do a map with a list. So `HashMap<String, List<int[]>> H = new HashMap<String, List<int[]>>();` and then add the values to the list. I'll post an answer for you to see.

Comment: @limelights If he stores an array of `int`, wouldn't he need a `List<Integers>` instead of a `List` of arrays of `int` ?

Comment: I'm guessing he needs the arrays for something so the List can store the int array just fine. There are perhaps better ways of doing it but I'm working off his example now. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you're after I believe.
Since a HashMap can only store unique keys you're forced to go with a list if you want multiple values for one (1) key.

There are perhaps better ways of achieving this but it's working and is pretty expressive in itself and pretty clear what it does and how.

The HashMap now accepts the List interface and can thusly accept any list-type that implements it. Which is pretty neat! :)

```
ArrayList<int[]> values = new ArrayList<int[]>();

values.add(new int[]{1,2});
values.add(new int[]{1,3});

HashMap<String, List<int[]>> H = new HashMap<String, List<int[]>>(); 

H.put("drdetroit", values);

for(String key : H.keySet()) {
    for(int[] array : H.get(key)){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `Arrays.toString(H.get("drdetroit"));`

Comment: this prints only the first value not the second one

Comment: That is because a Map can only have 1 value per key, you override the first with the second

Comment: @Aviram Segal: Is there an object that I can use that allows multiple values per key?

Comment: Apache commons collections got a MultiValueMap http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiValueMap.html

Comment: `HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>` ? you could maybe try this one.

Comment: Guava's [`ListMultimap`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) is one generics-enabled solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(H.get("drdetroit")));
```

I - stands for `int` array and c3c749 is **hashcode**

Comment: c3c749 is not hashCode, it is memory address. I@c3c749 is read as Integer at c3c749.

Comment: @Vash look at Quoi's answer

Comment: @NarendraPathai, My mistake. That is hex of hash.

Answer (score 0):

Because you try to make a String out of an array!

You could do for example:

```
String myArray = H.get("drdetroit");
System.out.println(myArray[0]);
```

Comment: Mm, no, he just prints it's object value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to print array values -

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(H.get("drdetroit")));
```

`H.get("drdetroit").toString()` returns array class name and @ and hashcode in hexString.

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```